# Custom shape with CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

For a menu I would like to had a custom shape designed in pure CSS.

The shape should look like this:

[image]

Here what I tried with `:before` and `:after`

```css
h5:before{
 border-color: #dbb900;
 padding: 0px 5px;
 border-left: 2px solid #2f3539;
 border-right: 2px solid #2f3539;
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 top: 50%;
 left: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 10px;
 width: 2px;
 margin: 15px auto 0px;
 right: 0px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
h5:after{
 border-right: 2px solid #2f3539;
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 top: 50%;
 left: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 10px;
 width: 2px;
 margin: 15px auto 0px;
 right: 0px;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h5>My title</h5>
```

What I missing here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're mainly talking about the location of those borders you've added to `:before` & `:after`.

---

First of all, when you use `position: absolute;`, it will be absolute relative to certain element.

Currently, it's relative to the whole document.

If you say `h5 { position: relative; }`, `:before` & `:after` will position themselves relative to h5 with their respective absolute positions.

---

After you've done the above, you find that `h5` spans across the whole width of the document.

This is because `h5` is `display: block;` by default. `display: inline-block;` will be more suitable in this case.

Check out the snippet below.

```css
h5:before{
 border-color: #dbb900;
 padding: 0px 5px;
 border-left: 2px solid #2f3539;
 border-right: 2px solid #2f3539;
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 top: 50%;
 left: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 10px;
 width: 2px;
 margin: 15px auto 0px;
 right: 0px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
h5:after{
 border-right: 2px solid #2f3539;
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 top: 50%;
 left: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 15px; /*10px;*/
 width: 2px;
 margin: 15px auto 0px;
 right: 0px;
 /*opacity: 0;*/
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
h5 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h5>My title</h5>
```

Comment: Ho wow! It's working. How to place this css shape right after the text please ? Thanks.

Comment: You can just add some padding to `h5` to give some space for the shape and then adjust the `:before` and `:after` positioning with `top` & `left` to be wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way with one element and without complex code:

```css
.element {
  font-size:30px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-bottom:30px; /*to control the space of the lines under the text*/
  background:
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) 50% 100%/2px 20px, /*middle line [width:2px height:20px]*/
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(50% - 5px) calc(100% - 5px)/2px 15px, /*left line [width:2px height:15px]*/
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) calc(50% + 5px) calc(100% - 5px)/2px 15px; /*right line [width:2px height:15px]*/
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">some Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) combined with [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) on the [: The Navigation Section element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav)

[image]

```css
nav{
  
}
nav ul{
    text-align: center
}
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 12px;
}
nav a{
    color: black;
    position : relative;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 10px
}
nav a:before,
nav a:after{
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 2px;
    background: currentcolor;
    color: orange;
    top: 100%;
}
nav a:before{ 
    margin-left: -1px;
    height: 32px;
}
nav a:after{ 
    margin-left: -10px; 
    height: 20px;
    box-shadow: 18px 0 0 0 currentColor;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```